# jquery selector to select all text inputs not of a specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In the following jquery code, I need to skip some input boxes whose classname not equals to item

> input[type=text][class!=item] ,  this doesn't works

. How to add this exception ?

```
     $(document)  
                    .on('focus', 'input[type=text]")', function() { 
                        $('.footer').css('position', 'absolute');
                        $('.footer').css('bottom', ''); 
                    })

                    .on('blur', 'input[type=text]', function() { 
                        $('.footer').css('position', 'fixed');  
                        $('.footer').css('bottom', '0');
                    });
```

Comment: Note that you can provide an object to `css()` to set multiple properties in a single call. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) for more details

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : actually am doing this in my hybrid phonegap app wherein in my android mobile when I tap a text box the android keyboard pops up and takes my footer also along with it at its top, so i need to stop this behavior and make my footer always stick at the bottom.

Comment: Right, but my point is you don't need to make multiple calls to `css()` on the same element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Can you please suggest me a more robust solution to accomplish this task in my hybrid app as this one ain't flawless and the user is able to see that the footer first gets un-sticked from the bottom and then the keyboard pops up over it, so this one's too slow.

Comment: There's nothing that can really be done about that. Speed is an inherent problem in hybrid JS apps. Use native if you want better performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("input[type='text']:not('.classname')");
```

So, adding and modifying your code:

```js
$(document)
  .on('focus', "input[type='text']:not('.classname')", function() {
    $('.footer').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'bottom': 'auto'
    });
  })

  .on('blur', "input[type='text']:not('.classname')", function() {
    $('.footer').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'bottom': 0
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `:not()` selector in your query:

See snippet for results:

```js
// 2 solutions here
// Using the class attribute $("input[type=text]:not([class=item])")
console.log($("input[type=text]:not([class=item])").length, "element matched.");

// Using the class selector $("input[type=text]:not('.item')")
console.log($("input[type=text]:not('.item')").length, "element matched.");


// Using the code from your question:
$("input[type=text]:not('.item')").on('focus', function() {
  $('.footer').css('position', 'absolute');
  $('.footer').css('bottom', '');
})

$("input[type=text]:not('.item')").on('blur', function() {
  $('.footer').css('position', 'fixed');
  $('.footer').css('bottom', '0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="item">
<input type="text" class="item">
<input type="text">
```

I've added your code in my snippet, but I don't know what you want to do with your `.footer` element.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but how do I add this inside the .on focus code which I have mentioned, would be great if you could mentioned the full code along with my code

Comment: @sqlchild I've modified my answer.

Comment: actually am doing this in my hybrid phonegap app wherein in my android mobile when I tap a text box the android keyboard pops up and takes my footer also along with it at its top, so i need to stop this behavior and make my footer always stick at the bottom